# Unable to Connect AWS MSK from a application hosted in Openshift ROSA(AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am doing some POC to see if my application can access AWS MSK or not. We are using Multi-VPC using IAM role based authentication. We have already configured in both MSK and Rosa side (created IAM role, attached the policy with required permission).

Now I logged to my Client node and installed kafka client, then used the below config with bootstrap server to see if we can create sample topic, which worked without any issue.

**Config:**

```
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism = AWS_MSK_IAM
sasl.jaas.config = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

Now using the same above config I am deploying(using helm) a sample application (https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui) on the same node but encountered an error:- (it is very big error, so highlighted the important ones)

```
SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from any provider in the chain ...
You must specify roleArn and roleSessionName .... 
profile cannot be null
```

tried to provide the roleArn as well but didnt work.

Could you please let me know what is wrong with it where if we use kafka client(kafka-topics.sh) it is working ?